# What node library should I use for managing logs?

Tags: library, node.js, logs, log-analysis

I am getting a set of logs from one application (in a txt file) and I have to separate, process and then send them one by one to another app. The format of the logs that I'm receiving is like this:

```
2019-05-07 10:46:49,532 [6] INFO App1 - Message1
2019-05-07 10:46:51,532 [6] INFO App1 - Message2
```

And I have to send them one by one as a JSON object in this format:

```
{
"timestamp":"2018-07-12T17:53:44.613+05:30",
"senderApp":"ThisApp",
"senderUser":"Mike",
"logLevel":"Error",
"logMessage":"This is the error we received!"
}
```

Is there any library that could help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/es/products/logstash) is a tool to process and transform data from multiple sources.

As you might guess from the name, is mainly used to extract and format data from logs and send it to a storage (e.g: Elastic Search).

It is configured using a DSL with the following components:

- inputs: it could be a *file* in you example
- filters: for instance, *grok*, that allows you to extract data using regular expressions
- outputs: also a *file* for your case.